# How to modify object using php?

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have an array object $obj. When I do print_r($obj), it gives the following output:

```
Array
(
[0] => Sabai_Link Object
    (
        [_url:Sabai_Link:private] => SabaiFramework_Application_Url Object
            (
                [_data:SabaiFramework_Application_Url:private] => Array
                    (
                        [script_url] => http://demodomain.com/test/questions/ask
                        [params] => Array
                            (
```

> ```
>                                 [term_id] => 4
> ```

```
                            )

                        [fragment] => 
                        [separator] => &amp;
                    )

            )

        [_label:Sabai_Link:private] => Ask Question
        [_options:Sabai_Link:private] => Array
            (
                [icon] => pencil
            )

        [_attributes:Sabai_Link:private] => Array
            (
                [class] => sabai-btn sabai-btn-small sabai-btn-success
            )

    )

)
```

I want to modify the $obj object so that add one more item to the params array like this:

```
[tab_id] => 1
```

so, the modified item will be as:

> ```
> [term_id] => 4
> [tab_id] => 1
> ```

How to do this using php?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to push one or more element onto the end of array, you should use: array_push

```
     array_push ( $params , array('term_id' => 4) )
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically, you want to add a value to a nest array, correct?  In that case, use syntax similar to what RaNdoM_PoWneD provided, just extended. Something like this:

```
$obj[0][_url:Sabai_Link:private][_data:SabaiFramework_Application_Url:private][params]["tab_id"] = 1
```

Note, your naming syntax is a little odd, and I am not familar with issues names such as `_url:Sabai_Link:private` might introduce, but something like this should work.

Comment: thank you for your answer..I tried it but ":" is causing error. I think I cannot have that..

Comment: @manoj Yeah, that seems like it is probably the issue.  If you are able to change that without it altering the functionality you want, the the method above should work.  Good luck with whatever solution you come up with!